# Extract JSON key-value map with a regex from a file

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm not really strong in regexes and tried to solve a problem with a parser written by hands, my own bicycle, which failed on some inputs unpredicted by me though, the problem is as follows: I have JavaScript i18n files that, along with translations, contain some other configuration stuff that may be defined somewhere in a file (that's the main reason why it's pretty hard to handle the problem with hand made parser), so the file is something like that:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    //some configuration stuff (some other stuff may be insterted)
    var translations = angular.module('module.translations.languages.enUs', []);

    translations.constant('translationsName', {
     "first_label":"first_label_value",
     "second_label":"second_label_value"
     //etc
});

}());
```

The example above is only one of possible template options, but they all have one thing in common - translation labels are defined as a key-value json which is nothing but a java map serialized to json. 
My goal is to get only these key-value json from a file, deserialize it to map, do some operations with it and insert it back again. So the question is: perhaps someone has ready and proven regex that could handle this kind of situation - find a map of key-value json in a text? If so, I would be really grateful for that!
Thanks, 
Cheers,
Andrey

Answer (score 8):

You could use this regexp to find `"key":"value"` pairs :

`"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)",?`

*Group 1* is the key, *Group 2* is the value

It will also find `"key":   "value"`,  `"key" :"value"` or `"key" :   "value"` pairs.

[Demo on regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/r3mq0n) (click the **Java** button then click **Test** button)

Also a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE3c0x/5) on regex101

**Explanation**

`"([^"]+)"` : Capture any character but a double-quote between double-quotes (this is the *key*)

`\s*?` : Followed by zero or more whitespace

`\s*` : Followed by a colon

`\s*` : Followed by zero or more whitespace

`"([^"]+)"` : Capture any character but a double-quote between double-quotes (this is the *value*)

Comment: I had similar issue. i used your regex  ,it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Great ! Thanx for your feedback.

Comment: Having trouble where the value is a number, and therefore has no double quotes?

Comment: Have got closer with the following regex:  

`("([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)")|("([^"]+)"\s*:\s*(\d+\.?\d*))|("([^"]+)"\s*:\s*(\w+))`  

but this does not cope with any overlapping, e.g.  

`"list":"{\"num\":"\1\" ,`  

returns only:  `"list":"{\"`

Comment: Hi @MetricRat, replacing the second group capture `"([^"]+)"` with `(?:"([^"]+)"|(\d+))` should answer your request. Here is an example : https://regex101.com/r/bRacQh/2

Comment: Thank you, in the end, I got there another way: `("([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)")|("([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)")|("([^"]+)"\s*:\s*(\d+\.?\d*))|("([^"]+)"\s*:\s*(\w+))`

Comment: How to fetch if value is array . Example: [ "sample1", "sample2" ]

Comment: In this specific case, you would just replace braces with brackets and the colon delimiter by a comma, like this https://regex101.com/r/pNVPx5/1

Comment: for values without quotes, how to fetch?